# Create multiple walls each made out of random boards

Tags: geometry-nodes

I can randomize the wall from a collection made out of different boards but then that wall is instanced on all points. I want each instance to be randomly generated again.[image]

Comment: either provide your blend file or tell us exactly what you want to randomize? the material? the position/rotation? for me it looks like that you just randomize the color of each plane....

Comment: The color is just to display that those are different objects. The wall is made by instancing boards from a collection on a line. I want to then place multiple copies of that wall on a circle and have them each be made out of a different combination of boards. I can randomize how the wall is made with a random value in the instance index. Is there a way to make it so that each wall has a different seed ?

Comment: Do you explicitly need different objects, or would it be enough to have different materials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by inverting the sequence of instantiation, so that you first create all your points. After doing this, you create all instances of boards at once.

[image: Node network]

[image: result]

[image: rendered]